# Adding Text views in multiple rows in Relative layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, textview

I'm trying to achieve the following view in image programmatically.
I am adding text view to relative layout dynamically. 
My problem is text view are added as required to right of each text view added prior. 
But after one row completion other text views are hidden due to the size of screen.
How to add other remaining text view to next line after they added in one line. 
Whether my approach is wrong to achieve this. Please guide me. Thanks.

Here is code :

```
RelativeLayout llTags = (RelativeLayout)res.findViewById(R.id.layout_tags);
for (int i = 0; i < arrTags.size(); i++) {  
    View view =  (getActivity()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_tags, null);
    tvTag = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_tags);
    tvTag.setText(arrTags.get(i));
    view.setId(i+1);            
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpFirst = new 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if(i!=0){
       lpFirst.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,view.getId()-1);             
       lpFirst.setMargins(5,0,0,0);
    }
    llTags.addView(view, i, lpFirst);           
}
```

[image]

Comment: You just want to display TextView rows, one under the other?

Comment: @Jahckyto yes but textview depends on array of tags availabe. how to decide how many text views in one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after much googling got the solution from here :

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Need to create custom flow layout instead of relative layout used.Custom flow layout will adjust child views accordingly in rows.