# Android: Custom FlowLayout

Tags: android, flowlayout

I want to make [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3gaacme8E3oQUcyVWhKeHpjeE0/view?usp=sharing) kind of menu of tags in android. Fill layout dynamically and align to center.
*How can I do that?*

Edited using library recommended by @Dory

```
<FlowLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:f="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    f:debugDraw="false"
    f:weightDefault="0"
    f:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="12dip"
    android:paddingBottom="12dip"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/l_flow"/>



   <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"/>
```

Flowlayout in one xml file Button is in another xml file. I'm inflating Button then fLayout.addView(button);

[what I get is this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3gaacme8E3obTdBUWI5UTNVc1k/view?usp=sharing)   Padding top and bottom between views is higher than expected

Comment: https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: I'd try using a vertical linear layout instead.

Comment: is this libs useful to you ?

Comment: yes. I have answered to my question below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally I did it with help of [this](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout) library. I have used only class FlowLayout and attr.xml My main.xml looks like this:

```
    <com.example.FlowTest.FlowLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/flow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

and my item layout looks like this:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
```

And in my Activity's onCreate method:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    mFlowLayout = (FlowLayout) findViewById(R.id.flow);

    String [] names = {"goods", "shops", "cars", "washing machine","blablabla","clothes","books"};

    for(int i = 0; i<names.length;i++){
        Button b = (Button)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_flow,mFlowLayout, false);
        b.setText(names[i]);
        mFlowLayout.addView(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878741/adding-text-views-in-multiple-rows-in-relative-layout-programmatically), you can use [this](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) library

**Edit:**

There is attributes provided in the where you can set `horizontal` and `vertical`spacing of the `Flow Layout`. See below sample xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:f="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">   
    <FlowLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    f:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    f:verticalSpacing="5dp" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: that library helped me but when I add views dynamically it failed. The space(vertical) between views too high and I can't manage them

Comment: @user3657472 could you please elaborate more on your issue

Comment: but in library no f:horizontalSpacing f:verticalSpacing

Comment: @user3657472 okie.. I have used this library long back. Layoutspacing are now converted into margin. Are you infalting the buttons dynamically or in xml ?

Comment: button in xml.  I am inflating it in activity --> Button b = (Button)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_flow,fLayout, false);  Then adding it to fLayout --->fLayout.addView(b);

Comment: @Dory any idea ... i want to select only one item at a time and selected item background color should be BLUE.when user select another one then only selected color will be BLUE.and all other will be in grey